# showing a set is a subgroup of a normaliser

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$ and defined $N_{G}\left ( H \right )=\left \{ g \in G \mid g^{-1}Hg=H \space\ \right \}$

Show that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $N_{G}\left ( H \right ).$

The Normal subgroup test to show this, in principle. However, I am unable to show that $H$ is a subgroup of the normaliser. I must be missing trivial but I can't pin point it.

Could someone provide me with a hint? Thanks in advance

Comment: First, you should write up what it would mean for an element of $H$ to be an element in the normalizer of $H$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think I could use the one-step subgroup test to show that H is a subgroup of the normaliser.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft 
To your first comment: require $h \in H s.t h^{-1}Hh=H$

Comment: The one-step subgroup test is in order to show that something is a subgroup *given that it is already a subset*. You already know that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, so you just need to show that it is contained in its normalizer.

Comment: But how do I know that $h^{-1}Hh =H?$ This doesn't come across as very intuitive.@TobiasKildetoft

Comment: Just write up what that means when $h\in H$.

Comment: Suppose $\exists h \in H$. If $h^{-1}Hh=H$, then $h \in N_{G}(H)$. But for H to be contained in the normaliser of H in G, I need to show that all h in H are in the normaliser of H in G.

Comment: Yes, write up what it means that $hHh^{-1} = H$. Also, you should probably look into how to use quantifiers correctly.

Comment: It means Hg=gH.@TobiasKildetoft
Then, recall $Hg=gH$ IFF $g^{-1}Hg=H$.
So, we have $g^{-1}Hg=H$.

Comment: No, what does it mean on the level of elements?

Comment: It means h is in the normaliser of H in G?

Comment: No, write up what the elements of the set $hHh^{-1}$ are.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If I can establish that this is true for all h in H, my work is done. But I cannot justify that h^{-1}Hh =H for all h in H. That is why I had the $\exists$ quantifier.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft They are just all elements h in H.

Comment: The statement with the $\exists$ literally reads as  "suppose $H$ contains some element", which is clearly not what you meant.

Comment: Why are they all the elements of $H$ (and try not to reuse the specific element $h$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think I got it. Because H is a subgroup so all group axiom holds. $h^{-1}H \in H$, so, $h^{-1}Hh \in H$.

Comment: Yes, precisely.

Comment: Thanks for having patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g\in N_G(H)$. Then $g^{-1}Hg=H$.

Thus $Hg=gH$ and thus $H$ is a normal subgroup of its normalizer.

Let $h\in H$. Certainly $h^{-1}Hh=H$ due to the closure property of the subgroup $H$. Thus $h\in N_G(H)$. This shows that $H$ is contained in $N_G(H)$.

Comment: It seems that what the OP is having trouble with is showing that $H$ is in fact contained in its normalizer, not the normality.